# VScode failed to start the kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Failed to start the Kernel 'wonyong (Python 3.8.8)'. 
View Jupyter log for further details. listen EFAULT: bad address in system call argument 127.0.0.1:9003
```

I cannot use jupyter notebook in vscode with this message.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

typing the following command:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```